# SQL concatenation with special pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL concatenation issue I am having difficulty with. Here are the columns I would like to concatenate:

```
Team    Date    Item Code
1   1/23/2015   DD-12345
1   1/24/2015   DD-12345
1   1/30/2015   LL-4545
1   1/31/2015   LL-4545
1   1/31/2015   LL-4545
1   2/1/2015    LL-4545
1   2/1/2015    LL-4545
1   2/2/2015    LL-4545
1   2/2/2015    LL-4545
1   2/2/2015    SS-2348
1   2/3/2015    SS-2348
1   2/3/2015    JJ-1212
1   2/3/2015    JJ-1212
1   2/3/2015    TT-6765
1   2/4/2015    TT-6765
1   2/4/2015    RR-4567
1   2/4/2015    RR-4567
1   3/1/2015    RR-4567
1   3/5/2015    RR-4567
1   3/5/2015    YY-6764
1   3/5/2015    YY-6764
```

Desired result (please see below):

If Item code doesn't change from one month to another (e.g. LL-4545 doesn't change from Jan to Feb, then the previous month number is used till the item code changes and then the new month # i.e.Feb is used etc.Similar pattern for RR-4567. I have tens of thousands of rows, over several months/years with this pattern and I couldn't figure out a code to accomplish this. Please help me. Thanks a lot!

```
Team Month Item Code Pattern
Team 1  Month 1  DD-12345
Team 1  Month 1  DD-12345
Team 1  Month 1  LL-4545
Team 1  Month 1  LL-4545
Team 1  Month 1  LL-4545
Team 1  Month 1  LL-4545
Team 1  Month 1  LL-4545
Team 1  Month 1  LL-4545
Team 1  Month 1  LL-4545
Team 1  Month 2  SS-2348
Team 1  Month 2  SS-2348
Team 1  Month 2  JJ-1212
Team 1  Month 2  JJ-1212
Team 1  Month 2  TT-6765
Team 1  Month 2  TT-6765
Team 1  Month 2  RR-4567
Team 1  Month 2  RR-4567
Team 1  Month 2  RR-4567
Team 1  Month 2  RR-4567
Team 1  Month 3  YY-6764
Team 1  Month 3  YY-6764
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code and also what SQL you are using, mssql, postregres, mysql...

Comment: Is postregres a previous version? ;)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I use msft sql server 2014. My apologies!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sql-server-2012 and above you can use this query.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  [Item Code] ORDER BY [Date]) AS GRP
    FROM MyTable
)
select 
    'Team ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Team) AS Team,
    'Month ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, MIN(MONTH([Date])) OVER(PARTITION BY GRP,[Item Code] ) ) AS [Month],
    [Item Code] , GRP
from CTE
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Comment: Serkan, thanks a lot for your help!! This almost there but it always picks the lowest month number for ALL products with the same item code regardless of in which month and where it appears.

But my goal is to pick the previous month number only when the same item code transitions from end of one month to then next, e.g. LL-4545,   RR-4567. If those items show up again in the middle of November and end in November the concatenation should use 11, (not the absolute Min Month associated with it), if the items show up end of October and transition to Nov, it should pick 10 etc.

Comment: Serkan,this actually picked the month number of the current row i.e. the month number of the 'New Month' (even though the Item code did NOT change from end of previous month..say Feb 28 to the current month e.g. March 1 or 2). But the goal is to use previous (old month number) if the item  code remains unchanged from end of previous to current month. Thanks for all the help. Really appreciated!!!

Comment: Serkan, I finally figured out after adding an int ID column (not given above) and using it in the CTE order by clause (as opposed to using [date]). The int ID I used gave me an accurate GRP for each [Item Code] partition. Thanks a lot for helping me with this. Very much appreciated!!!!